# 2 finger scrolling doesn't work

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics, scrolling

How can I make my touchpad scrolling down with 2 fingers? I've tried to enter in my settings and set 2 fingers enabled but I don't have that button:

[image]

After that I've installed synaptic and used it but it doesn't work again.

Here is my output of xinput:

```
 Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse                 id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can make it work?

Comment: Maybe your touchpad is not supported yet. In this case you will have wait kernel updates.

Comment: A few weeks I've put the same question here and some one told me 3 commands in terminal, after I used that my scroll down with 2 finger work's. But I lose that commands and I've try to recap.

Comment: Please also add output of `dmesg | grep pnp; uname -r`. And specify Ubuntu version.